# Finding Unique Tuple and Column Permutations

Tags: mysql, sql, permutation

I have a table of `numbers` which consists of various `nums` from range `[0-9]`

```
 --------
 | nums |
 --------
 |  0   |
 |  1   |
 | .... |
 |  9   |
 --------
```

I want to take the cartesian product of this table multiple times (in fact, 8 times to be precise):

`SELECT * FROM numbers A, numbers B, numbers C, numbers D, ...`

Such that `A.nums` and `B.nums, ...` are unique combinations together AND they are not equal to the same value another number is.

Here's some sample output I would want to see:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(3, 2, 1, 0)
(2, 1, 3, 0)
(0, 2, 1, 3)
(0, 9, 8, 7)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5, 9)
(1, 9, 8, 7)
```

... BUT NO TUPLES like `(0, 0, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 2), etc.`  Tuples should also not be repeated, such as `(1, 2, 3, 4) and (1, 2, 3, 4)`
Every value in the tuple must be **different** from another value in the tuple.

I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this, but I've resorted to `A.nums != B.nums, ...` for every single possibility.  It seems relatively efficient; offering ~300 ms run-time for an 8-way cartesian product, but I would like to know if there's a simpler, more elegant solution with similar run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE nums (x INT);

INSERT INTO nums (x) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4); 

SELECT a.x, b.x, c.x, d.x 
FROM nums AS a 
JOIN nums AS b ON b.x NOT IN (a.x) 
JOIN nums AS c ON c.x NOT IN (a.x, b.x) 
JOIN nums AS d ON d.x NOT IN (a.x, b.x, c.x);
```